# Creating a data frame based on another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a program that will extract certain rows of a data frame that match a criteria and append them to another data frame. The criteria is that the first 7 characters of the GL_Account column is equal to 4000001.

I have other modifications I need to do to the main data frame as well but I'm not really having trouble with that.
I am new to python and a returning programmer from C++ so I'm probably not doing things in the ideal python way.

I have a while loop going iterating on highIter to iterate through the entire data frame.]
I've tried concatenating, and appending, but I believe there is a type issue.

dfglilsolation is a data frame where I want to place those GLs
dfExtract is where the data is

```
if dfExtract.at[hightIter, 'GL_Account'][0:7] == "4000001":
            entry = dfExtract.loc[hightIter]
            
            
            print(entry) #this is printing the correct data that needs to be moved into the other data frame
            dfglisolation = pandas.concat([dfglisolation, entry])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you don't need a loop since you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
dfExtractSubset = dfExtract[dfExtract['GL_Account'].startswith('4000001')]
dfglisolation = pandas.concat([dfglisolation, dfExtractSusbet], axis=0)
```